# Grails Autocomplete using JQuery

Tags: jquery, grails

I'm trying to implement autocomplete into my forms for my grails application. Currently with the code below, when you type any characters/words into the parameterName field it returns EVERY value within the parameter_name column.

As you can imagine I just want it to suggest values based on what I have already typed in. So if I type in 'card' it should suggest values starting with the word card. What modifications do I need to make to the code below in order to achieve this?

The function I have in the form.gsp:

```
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#parameterName" ).autocomplete({
  source: '${g.createLink(controller: 'templateInput', action: 'suggestedParameterNames')}'
  });
 });
</script>
```

The function I have in my controller for templateInput:

```
def suggestedParameterNames() {
    def suggestions = templatingService.getSuggestedParamNameValues()

    render suggestions as JSON
}
```

The function I have in my service:

```
def getSuggestedParamNameValues(){
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def row = sql.rows("select distinct parameter_name from template_input")

    return row
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: But you're not passing the entered text to the AJAX call, the controller or the query, so how could it possibly use it?

Comment: I'm new to JQuery/Ajax and this is my first experience of it. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: I suggest you follow the advice below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete provides a `term` parameter that contains the text the user has typed (assuming you are using the version at http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). So you first need to test that is being sent and then pass it onto your service:

```
def suggestedParameterNames(String term) { 
    log.debug "input text = ${term}"
    def suggestions = templatingService.getSuggestedParamNameValues(term)
    render suggestions as JSON
}
```

The usual way of searching for domain objects that contain your substring query is via a SQL like command using a dynamic finder:

```
def foundItems = MyDomain.findAllByFooLike(terms + "%", params)
```

or via SQL (guessing so might not be correct syntax)

```
def row = sql.rows("select distinct parameter_name from template_input where parameter_name like " + terms + "%")
```

And then you might have to massage the `List` of returned objects into a JSON structure that jQuery autocomplete is expecting (e.g. create a Groovy data structure that mimics the expected format and then return is `as JSON`.